# Postgres 9.5 update inner json field

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a json column. The object has nested fields e.g.

```
{
  "logo": {
    "url": "https://foo.bar"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The object has more fields, but the `url` field is the one that I want to update. I believe I should use something like json_set, but I'm lost regarding the json path. Can I have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `json` only with `jsonb` (but you can easily cast the existing value)

With `jsonb_set` you need to provide the path to the object you want to change, so that would be `'{logo,url}'`:

The following:

```
with t (data) as (
  values
    ('{
        "logo": { "url": "https://foo.bar", "something" : "some value"}, 
        "other" : { "one": "two"}
      }'::jsonb
    )
)
select jsonb_set(data, '{logo,url}', to_jsonb('http://bar.foo'::text))
from t;
```

<sup>(The `WITH` part is only there to generate dummy data)</sup>

returns:

```
jsonb_set                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"logo": {"url": "http://bar.foo", "something": "some value"}, "other": {"one": "two"}}
```

As you can see, only the `url` attribute was replaced, everything else is left as it is.

If your column is really a json, just use `your_column::jsonb` so that you can use `jsonb_set()`